# Opendr installation error (python2.7 & Ubuntu 16.04): failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-e1zPWl/opendr/

Tags: 16.04, python, pip, python-2.7

I am trying to set up `virtualenv` on Ubuntu 16.04. I have already installed
`pip (v.19.0.3)`, `scipy`, `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `scikit-image`, `deepdish`, `opencv_python`, `absl_py` and `ipdb`.

When I try to install `opendr` with

```
pip2 install opendr
```

I get this error:

```
Failed building wheel for opendr
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-e1zPWl/opendr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-T_iRmN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-e1zPWl/opendr/
```

Any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command to specify the version number:

```
pip install opendr==0.77
```